# Why folding worked in manifest file but don't work in other xml file (eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, folding

I try to  enable folding in xml files with eclipse.I checked the Enable Folding in eclipse  But don't work .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me with the `Eclipse XML Editors and Tools` (3.7.1.v201508271605   org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform)

[image: xml file]

You may need to install the above.

1. From the `Help` menu, choose `Install New Software`
2. Choose `Mars` from the drop down
3. Select `Eclipse XML Editors and Tools` and complete the install wizard.

[image: install]

Note that the `plugin.xml` has its own editor (the Plug-in manfiest editor) that handles XML editing. I believe both use some of the same underlying components.

Comment: Jonah Graham : Thank you

Comment: What is your eclipse name and version?

Comment: The answer above is for Eclipse Mars 4.5. The same should work with any version of Eclipse, but instead of Mars you need to select the update site that matches the version you installed.